# How to preserve the source text style while pasting in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

Using Java Swing, I am creating a simple .rtf file editor application using RTFEditorKit(). I am using JTextPane. I have added code for Bold, Italics, Underline text.

My problem scenario: 
I have two lines of text, first line of text is full of Bold style and second line of text is full of Italics style.
While copying some text from first line (which is Bold) to second line, after pasting the Bold text to second line it is displaying in Italics style.

Expected scenario: It should be in Bold style after pasting, it should preserve the style.
How can I achieve this in Java Swing? can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some old code I found years ago on a forum.

It copies individual attributes with the text.

No idea if it works with the RTFEditorKit:

```
/*
    crwood:
    http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5137992&tstart=0
*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class StyleTransfer {
    private JPanel getContent() {
        JTextPane left = new JTextPane();
        initialize(left);
        left.setDragEnabled(true);
        left.setTransferHandler(new StyleTransferHandler());
        JTextPane right = new JTextPane();
        right.setDragEnabled(true);
        right.setTransferHandler(new StyleTransferHandler());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(left));
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(right));
        panel.add( new JScrollPane( new JTextArea() ) );
        return panel;
    }

    private void initialize(JTextPane textPane) {
        String text = "This component models paragraphs that are composed of " +
            "runs of character level attributes. Each paragraph may have a " +
            "logical style attached to it which contains the default attributes " +
            "to use if not overridden by attributes set on the paragraph or " +
            "character run. Components and images may be embedded in the flow " +
            "of text."; // 0 - 319
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        createStyles(doc);
        setContent(doc, text);
        styleContent(doc);
    }

    private void createStyles(StyledDocument doc) {
        Style baseStyle = doc.addStyle("base", null);
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(baseStyle, "Lucida Sans Unicode");
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(baseStyle, 18);
        StyleConstants.setLeftIndent(baseStyle, 10f);

        Style style = doc.addStyle("bold", baseStyle);
        StyleConstants.setBold(style, true);

        style = doc.addStyle("italic", baseStyle);
        StyleConstants.setItalic(style, true);

        style = doc.addStyle("blue", baseStyle);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.blue);

        style = doc.addStyle("underline", baseStyle);
        StyleConstants.setUnderline(style, true);

        style = doc.addStyle("green", baseStyle);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.green.darker());
        StyleConstants.setUnderline(style, true);

        style = doc.addStyle("highlight", baseStyle);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.yellow);
        StyleConstants.setBackground(style, Color.black);
    }

    private void setContent(StyledDocument doc, String text) {
        try {
            doc.insertString(0, text, doc.getStyle("base"));
        } catch(BadLocationException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void styleContent(StyledDocument doc) {
        String[] names = {
            "underline", "highlight", "blue", "italic",
            "green", "green", "bold", "bold"
        };
        int[] starts  = { 22, 62, 116, 164, 233, 246, 261, 276 };
        int[] lengths = { 10, 26,  13,  18,   9,   9,  10,   6 };
        Style style = doc.getStyle("base");
        doc.setLogicalStyle(0, style);
        for(int j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
            style = doc.getStyle(names[j]);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(starts[j], lengths[j], style, false);
        }
    }

    public JMenuBar getMenuBar () {
        JMenuItem menuItem = null;
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Edit");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        menuItem = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction());
        menuItem.setText("Cut");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        menu.add(menuItem);
        menuItem = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction());
        menuItem.setText("Copy");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        menu.add(menuItem);
        menuItem = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction());
        menuItem.setText("Paste");
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        menu.add(menuItem);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        return menuBar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
        StyleTransfer test = new StyleTransfer();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setJMenuBar(test.getMenuBar());
        f.getContentPane().add(test.getContent());
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setLocation(100,50);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class StyleTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    String mimeType = DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType +
                          ";class=StyledString";
    DataFlavor styledStringFlavor;

    public StyleTransferHandler() {
        try {
            styledStringFlavor = new DataFlavor(mimeType);
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to create styledStringFlavor");
        }
    }

    public boolean canImport(JComponent comp, DataFlavor[] transferFlavors) {
        for(int j = 0; j < transferFlavors.length; j++) {
            if(styledStringFlavor.equals(transferFlavors[j]))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        JTextPane textPane = (JTextPane)c;
        int start = textPane.getSelectionStart();
        int end = textPane.getSelectionEnd();
        StyledString ss = new StyledString("");
        if(start != -1 && start != end) {
            String text = textPane.getSelectedText();
            ss = new StyledString(text);
            StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
            extractAttributes(doc, start, end, ss);
        }
        System.out.println(ss);
        return new StyledStringTransferable(ss);
    }

    private void extractAttributes(StyledDocument doc, int selectionStart,
                                   int selectionEnd, StyledString styledStr) {
        int pos = selectionStart;
        styledStr.logicalStyle = doc.getLogicalStyle(pos);
        while(pos < selectionEnd) {
            Element element = doc.getCharacterElement(pos);
            AttributeSet attrs = element.getAttributes();
            int endOffset = element.getEndOffset();
            int end = (endOffset < selectionEnd) ? endOffset : selectionEnd;
            styledStr.addAttributes(attrs, pos, end);
            pos = end;
        }
    }

    /**
     * MOVE is not supported in superclass implementation
     * and exportDone is implemented to do nothing - see api.
     */
    public void exportAsDrag(JComponent comp, InputEvent e, int action) {
        super.exportAsDrag(comp, e, action);
        Clipboard clip = comp.getToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        exportDone(comp, clip, action);
    }

    /**
     * MOVE is not supported in superclass implementation
     * and exportDone is implemented to do nothing - see api.
     */
    public void exportToClipboard(JComponent comp, Clipboard clip, int action) {
        super.exportToClipboard(comp, clip, action);
        exportDone(comp, clip, action);
    }

    public void exportDone(JComponent comp, Clipboard clip, int action) {
        JTextPane textPane = (JTextPane)comp;
        if(action == MOVE) {
            int offset = textPane.getSelectionStart();
            int length = textPane.getSelectionEnd() - offset;
            StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
            try {
                doc.remove(offset, length);
            } catch(BadLocationException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return COPY_OR_MOVE;
    }

    public boolean importData(JComponent comp, Transferable t) {
        if(canImport(comp, t.getTransferDataFlavors())) {
            StyledString styledStr = null;
            try {
                styledStr = (StyledString)t.getTransferData(styledStringFlavor);
                List attrs = styledStr.attrs;
                List locs = styledStr.locs;
                JTextPane textPane = (JTextPane)comp;
                int pos = textPane.getCaretPosition();
                StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
                Style logicalStyle = styledStr.logicalStyle;
                // Insert the text.
                try {
                    doc.insertString(pos, styledStr.text, logicalStyle);
                } catch(BadLocationException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                // Appy the style runs to the inserted text.
                for(int j = 0; j < attrs.size(); j++) {
                    AttributeSet as = (AttributeSet)attrs.get(j);
                    Location loc = (Location)locs.get(j);
                    doc.setCharacterAttributes(pos, loc.length, as, false);
                    pos += loc.length;
                }
                return true;
            } catch(UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
                System.out.println("importData UnsupportedFlavor: " +
                                    ufe.getMessage());
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("importData IO Error: " + ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    class StyledStringTransferable implements Transferable {
        private StyledString styledString;

        StyledStringTransferable(StyledString ss) {
            styledString = ss;
        }

        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
                                  throws UnsupportedFlavorException {
            if(!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor))
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
            return styledString;
        }

        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return new DataFlavor[] { styledStringFlavor };
        }

        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return styledStringFlavor.equals(flavor);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "StyledStringTransferable: " + styledString;
        }
    }
}

class StyledString {
    String text;
    List attrs;
    List locs;
    Style logicalStyle;

    public StyledString(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        attrs = new ArrayList();
        locs  = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void addAttributes(AttributeSet atts, int start, int end) {
        attrs.add(atts);
        locs.add(new Location(start, end));
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("StyledString[");
        for(int j = 0; j < attrs.size(); j++) {
            sb.append("Attributes[");
            Enumeration e = ((AttributeSet)attrs.get(j)).getAttributeNames();
            while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
                Object key = e.nextElement();
                Object value = ((AttributeSet)attrs.get(j)).getAttribute(key);
                sb.append("key:" + key + ",value:" + value + ";");
            }
            sb.append("]");
            sb.append(" for " + locs.get(j));
            if(j < attrs.size()-1)
                sb.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

class Location {
    int start;
    int length;

    public Location(int start, int end) {
        this.start = start;
        length = end - start;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Location[start:" + start + ",length:" + length + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please give a exact code for copy & paste to preserve the source text style, sorry, I am a newbie to java.

Comment: I did give you the exact code. You can copy/paste/compile and test. `I am a newbie to java` - then maybe you need to start with something simpler. We an not here to write the code for you. You have been given the code that appears to do what you want. You need to take the time to understand it.

Comment: thanks for your advice, your code throws null pointer exception, thats why I asked, anyway thanks

Comment: @AbiSaran, works fine for me (using JDK8 on Windows 7), or I would not have posted the code. All you do is 1) selected some text 2) click on "Edit" and then "Copy" 3) click on the second text pane 4) click on "Edit" and then "Paste".  `your code throws null pointer exception` - nowhere did you state that in your original comment and nowhere have you stated the steps you used to cause the NPE. We are not mind readers. We can't guess what you are doing. I have no idea if you did something wrong or if this is a platform issue.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the previous comment correctly, I am using JDK 8 and windows 10, I will debug and check it once again, thanks

Comment: i resolved it, my expected scenario is working fine now, thanks.